# Spread categorical variables iinto new non-Boolean columns

Tags: r, pivot

Example data follows:

```
 id   sy    OC
13693 2017  1
13752 2017  5
13693 2017  4
44555 2018  3
```

What am I doing incorrectly for the following code?

```
SORs.pivot(index='id',columns="sy",values='OC').add_prefix('sy').reset_index()
```

I have never seen "pivot"ing used within R before, but I am eager to learn, once I get past this hurdle.

I wish for the final output to be something like the following:

```
 id   sy2017  sy2018
13693 1       na
13752 5       na
13693 4       na
44555 na      3
```

I adapted it from [this Stack Overflow page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50862194/categorical-variables-into-multiple-columns).

I am also looking to get the summation of the values within the cells for the repeating ids (13693).

### Update

First, please let me apologize for mixing R and Python. That was just silly on my part.

I am still having problems with the data even though I used some of the solutions:

Now this yields a df with over 200,000 records - but the logic works, and I am ready to spread the columns out.

I tried two different ways but neither worked.

First I tried:

```
reshape(dat2, idvar="id", timevar="sy", direction="wide").
```

All this yielded was a df with two columns. The first was the subjectkey and the next said DistinctOrderCound.2017:2018 - and the latter column is just a column of NAs.

Then I tried:

```
spread(dat2, key = sy, value=value).
```

This yielded a Error saying duplicate values for rows and a sample listing of the duplicates.

I think the reshape should work and work nicely. I do not think there are any issues with the summation any more as I took care of that with a pre-query.

Comment: You tried to use python code in R (the question you linked is python, not R).

Comment: *"I have never seen "pivot"ing used within R before"* Pivoting is a *very* common task in R (you will see at least a hand-full of questions about this every day here on SO); in the R domain it's more commonly known as "spreading" data, or "casting/reshaping data from long to wide". Some more popular methods to do this are `tidyr::spread`, `reshape::reshape`, `data.table::dcast`. I have never heard of `SORs.pivot` nor do I know which R package this function comes from. I recommend sticking to the more popular packages/methods.

Comment: [continued] Take a look at [How to reshape data from long to wide format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5890584/how-to-reshape-data-from-long-to-wide-format).

Comment: `library(reshape2); dcast(DF, OC + id ~ paste0("sy", sy))[-1]`

Answer (score 0):

The R package `tidyr` uses the `spread` function for this task. In your case, you could try `tidyr::spread(data, sy, OC)` which should accomplish your goals. For more on `tidyr::spread` and `tidyr::gather`, see [this blog post](http://garrettgman.github.io/tidying/)

Comment: Thanks a bunch. But - and this is the geek in me - may it be accomplished with the pivoting?

Comment: @Zach `spread`ing and pivoting are the same thing. See my comment to your OP above.

Answer (score 0):

dcast() solves everything. Kind of weird how simple it is.

Thank you to everyone!

Comment: Would you edit this to show how you used `dcast`, so this answer is as useful as possible for future readers? Thank you.